# Customize angular material moment datepicker display

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-moment, angular-material-datetimepicker

I'm working now with Angular material datepicker and I use the moment dateadapter as dateadapter.

It works really great but the displayed date on the input doesn't suit my needs. It shows a date in DD/MM/YYYY format while I need it in DD/MM/YY. (eg. 25/7/2019 should be 25/07/19)

Since I can't find documentation on this display format, I'm gonna need a little help to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your custom date formats.
In your ts file do like this:

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YY'
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-component',
  templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.
Can you explain why does the constant MY_FORMATS need to be exported for it to work? I tried it before posting my question here but I omitted the export and of course, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Custom Date Format from material date format
```

export const CustomFormat = {
    display: {
           dateInput: 'DD/MM/YY'
       }
    };
    @Component({
    selector: 'datecomponent',
    templateUrl: './datecomponent.html',
    providers: [
         {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CustomFormat},
      ]
    })